# how to interpolate solution in boost odeint bulirsch_stoer_dense_out

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I have been only recently working with boost odeint in c++. Most probably my question is trivial, however it would be great if anyone could help me on how to interpolate implicitly a solution of bulirsch_stoer_dense_out stepper (adaptive) to a denser interval (than the one generated by error tolerances), if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dense output version of the bulirsch stoer stepper in combination with integrate_const:

```
bulirsch_stoer_dense_out< state_type > stepper { 1.0e-6 , 1.0e-6  };
integrate_const( stepper , sys , x , t_start , dt , t_end , observer );
```

`dt` is here the interval you need. `integrate_const` will perform adaptive step size control and interpolate the solution to your time interval. You can also check [bulirsch_stoer.cpp](https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/blob/master/examples/bulirsch_stoer.cpp) in the example folder of odeint.